# How/where to load value object that is entity in different BC in DDD and CQRS/ES based system

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have gone through this great tutorial: http://www.cqrs.nu/tutorial/cs/01-design and trying to do my app same way.

According to my previous questions I know, that what is entity in one BC can be represented as value object containing identifier of entity in other BC and optionally any other parameter. (I put those identifiers to Core BC.)

Now, let's say I have two BC: `PlansEditor` and `Subscribing`.

In `PlansEditor`, given there is `Editor` (person with role), when he creates `Plan` with some params like `frequency` and `vip`, then `Plan` is created.

In `Subscribing`, given there is `Customer` and some available `Plan`s, when customer subscribes to a `Plan`, then `Subscription` is created.

Plans here could be just VO with frequency and VIP parameters, because Subscription needs just them (to protect invariants). But customer clicks to subscribe to a plan and request with id of plan is sent.

So I start my BC lifecycle with id of customer and id of plan he subscribed to. I need to load/create that `Plan` "value object" (which is really entity in `PlansEditor` BC) by given identifier somewhere.

**Where and how should I acquire that Plan VO in `Subscribing` BC?**

I thought in application layer through Event Repository - to be able to send `SubscribeCustomerToPlanCommand(Customer, Plan)` containing this value object. But `Subscribing` BC would then need to know that `Plan` as entity in `PlansEditor` exists in order to load it and translate it to `Plan` as VO, which is unacceptable - one BC would need other to function properly.

Or should I just get informations needed to create `Plan` VO from some read model and do that in application layer, is that convenient? Or how and where? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell `Plan` wouldn't be a VO in either contexts. It's not because one BC has the authority on an entity's life cycle that the entity becomes a VO in other contexts (it could).

If the downstream context needs to stay aware of the lifecycle of an entity in a remote context then this entity should probably be modeled as an entity in the downstream context as well.

For instance, I suppose that `Plan`s can be deactivated at some point that and it wouldn't make sense to allow subscribing to these? That would be a good indicator that `Plan` is not a simple value in the **Subscribing** context.

There are multiple strategies when it comes to BCs integration, but if you favor availability over consistency then messaging is most likely the better option. The upstream context would publish events on a messaging infrastructure and these would get consumed by the downstream context, allowing it to keep it's local copy of the entity state in sync.

> "BC would then need to know that Plan as entity in PlansEditor exists
>   in order to load it and translate it to Plan as VO, which is
>   unacceptable - one BC would need other to function properly"

Any integration strategy will require some level of coupling, but that coupling should be abstracted away in an anti-corruption layer.

Comment: Actually, when editor removes plan, all subscribers to that plan in Subscribing BC should stay subscribed to (_any_) plan with same params they were while subscribing. Only new subscribers should not be allowed to subscribe, because it does not exists (in `PlansEditor` BC). But It seems to me too complicated to maintain `Plan` entity in Subscribing BC, just because I am well satisfied with actual copy of state of `Plan` in `PlansEditor` BC into `Plan` VO at particular time when subscribing.

Comment: @Tom Well, in that case `Plan` could be a VO that you still acquire through a service that is part of your Subscriber's context's anti-corruption layer. Keep in mind that you cannot have strong consistency between both contexts (e.g. a customer may subscribe to a plan that has just been deactivated).

Comment: To add my ZAR0.02 :) --- agreed, the entity is *not* necessarily a VO in the downstream but you probably have a *different* representation of that concept... so perhaps a `SubscribedPlan` or some such.  This means that the upstream BC is still the *system of record* and you should handle all attributes belonging to *that* BC within a VO of sorts as you should most definitely *not* be changing them but using integration patterns to update them downstream.  You are free to change the values belonging to your downstream BC.

Comment: @EbenRoux The concept can be named `Plan` in both contexts while still being a different representation. You subscribe to a `Plan`, not a `SubscribedPlan`.

Comment: Yip, one could do that.  It'll depend on what the domain experts use, I guess.. so very much centered around the UL.  However, if it is a different concept it makes it easier to reason about if it has a distinct name representing that concept.  But agreed, you can use the same name.  In an *Identity & Access* BC there is a `User` but we might very well call it something else in another BC.  Just thinking along *those* lines.

Comment: @plalx Great, thank you, anti-corruption layer is what solves my problem! It also took me to context maps and whole chapter 14 in my freshly delivered Evan's big blue book. Another missing piece in this approach uncovered :)